# Create a new line if cells equals a value from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lemmatization

Using this dataframe:

```
            ##    doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id token_id       token      lemma  upos xpos
            ## 1    doc1            1           1        1 Linguistics Linguistic  NOUN  NNS
            ## 2    doc1            1           1        2        also       also   ADV   RB
            ## 3    doc1            1           1        3       deals       deal  NOUN  NNS
            ## 4    doc1            1           2        1   Something   something NOUN  NNS
            ## 5    doc1            1           2        2        Else        else NOUN  NNS
```

I'd like to have something like this in a .txt file:

```
Linguistic_NNS also_R deal_NN
something_NN else_NN
```

Except that using this code:

```
paste(text_anndf$lemma, "_", text_anndf$xpos, collapse = " ", sep = "")
```

I have this:

```
Linguistic_NN also_R deal_NN something_NN else_NN
```

Because it doesn't take into account the "sentence_id" values. Do I need to use a If or something similar ? Thanks

Comment: It would be good if you provided a reproducible sample data set and a concrete answer you are looking for from that data set. You can use dput() to create your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    unite(col = lemma_and_position,
          lemma, xpos, sep = '_') %>%
    group_by(sentence_id) %>%
    summarise(lemma_and_position = paste(lemma_and_position, collapse = ' '))
```

re @stompers advice: providing test data with `dput(your_data)` is always helpful!